# How to add active class to first accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I want add a class to a panel heading using jQuery, but am unable to do that.

```js
jQuery(".panel-deafult").each(function (index) {
    jQuery(this).children(".panel-heading:first").addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is on click event of the panel heading, to add the active class. Something along the lines of:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you're trying to do is to add the 'active' class to the first accordion tab for each accordion tab.

If that's right, here's what you'd do:

```
$('.panel-default').each(function(i,e){
var FirstPanel = $(e).children('.panel-heading')[0]; 
FirstPanel.addClass('active');
});
```